# Multiple simultanous animations, simulation of 'animate' easing and one 'step' call for a jQuery collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the problem, I've got a tree structure of html blocks, global container is of a fixed width(X) and height(Y). When i click one of the blocks on a level, all other blocks shrink to some size, while the clicked one gets enlarged to the leftover space, and the sublevels show up on it's place.

For all the shrinking i'm using default `animate` function with easing effect, **when shrinking 1 level**, to avoid enlargement bugs i have to do something like this:

```
$tabs.not($obj).animate({height:32<<$obj.getVerUp().length+"px"},{duration:300,
    step:function() {
        $obj.height(function(){
            var sum = 0;
            $tabs.not($obj).each(function(){
                sum += $(this).height();
            });
            return $obj.getCont().height()-sum+"px";
        });
    }
});
```

`$tabs` are all the tabs of current level, `$obj` - is the one tab that i want to enlarge

The **main problem** is:
When i open up a tab that is on a deep level, i have to animate all the tabs of higher levels to shrink a little bit more, thus the `$obj` X and Y would change, so the current animation has to use new values, but if i call 3 different animations on different levels i'm bound to get a bug, when **one of the animations on a deeper level finishes 1 step earlier**, while the one on the level above, would enlarge the object by 5-10 more pixels and that space wouldn't be used up.

The **second problem** is that there has to be about 50 object animating with easing at the same time, which is a little bit overkill.

And the **last problem** is when i call `step` callback on animation as shown above, i have a strange feeling that it calls the step **separately for each animation** of the `$tabs` collection, while **i need 1 step for all the tabs** in the list (to avoid unnecessary scripts)

There might be some other way to fix all that, but i have yet to discover all jQuery functions, so from what i see the only way is to simulate easing, and do everything in one single animation.

I don't really want to use `setInterval` and determining when do i need to clear it plus calculating each of the easing values, if there is a simple way doing it.

Does jQuery has some sort of empty animation easing, e.g.

```
$().css("height":starth+"px").animate({height:endh},{duration:300,
    step:function(fn) {

        // all the animation actions here via fn end value
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

---

What I need - is not a completely working solution in code, just some enlightenment in those subjects:

1. Is there a legal way to call one step function for a collection of animated elements, or, maybe, it does call `step` once when I use one `.animate` on collection.
2. I'd be really appreciated if someone would shed some light over how does jquery handle multiple `.animate`, would they be used in one global function that works on `.setInterval`? or would they be having massive number of those `.setIntervals` that are equivalent to setTimeout (which most browsers can't handle in large amounts);
3. Is there a way to simulate 'animate' easing, some function name maybe, or a special trick to achieve that (the only thing I see is a hidden element or 'window' property to change maybe)

Or some directed pushes with functions I should study, that could help me achieve my goals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess i pretty much found the answer to my questions:
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/fun-with-jquerys-animate/

Here's the empty animation from the link above with 1 step function with desired values, going to post the result later on if it all works out.

```
var from = {property: 0};
var to = {property: 100};

jQuery(from).animate(to, {
    duration: 100,
    step: function() {
        console.log( 'Currently @ ' + this.property );
    }
});
```

---

Yes it all worked great, no desynch, and a good speed, since only 1 animate, found making one universal function for the animation - waste of resourses, so it is pretty specific, but still, here it is:

```
animate: function($obj) {
    var T = this;
...

    T.arr = new Array();
    // gathering the array
    $obj.each(function(i){
        var size;
        T.arr[i] = {obj:$(this), rest:$(this).getSibl(), cont:$(this).getCont()}
        if($(this).hasClass("vert"))
        {
            size = "height";
            T.arr[i].to = yto;
        }
        else
        {
            size = "width";
            T.arr[i].to = xto;
            T.arr[i].children = $(this).getChld();
        }
        T.arr[i].rest.each(function(){
            $(this).attr("from",$(this)[size]());
        });
    });     

    // animating prop
    jQuery({prop:0}).animate({prop:1}, {
        duration: 300,
        step: function() {
            var i;
            var P = this;
            var newval;
            var sum;
            var size;
            for(i = 0; i < T.arr.length; i++)
            {
                size = T.arr[i].obj.hasClass("vert") ? "height":"width";
                sum = 0;
                T.arr[i].rest.each(function(){
                    // new value of width/height, determined by the animation percentage
                    newval = parseInt($(this).attr("from")) + (T.arr[i].to-$(this).attr("from"))*P.prop;
                    $(this)[size](newval);
                    sum += newval;
                });
                T.arr[i].obj[size](T.arr[i].cont[size]()-sum);
            }
        }
    });
},
```